# RxJS 5.4.3, You provided "undefined" where a stream was expected, nested forkJoins

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am super new to Angular and RxJS, I am used to using promises. I need to do the equivalent of a Promise.All(), I have an array of items that each need to make a HTTP call, and each of on those items has an array of items that each need to make a HTTP call. I have used forkJoin before for just a single array and it worked fine, but now I am nesting a forkJoin inside of a forkJoin and keep getting the error You provided "undefined" when a stream was expected. All the API calls are returning Observables, so could it be the result of one of the forkJoins themselves? Here is my code.

````
              .updateTrackSystemCompact({ ...uploadTrackSystemCompact, trackIds: null })
              .subscribe((uploadInspectionJob: UploadInspectionJob) => {
                uploadTrackSystemCompact = {
                  id: uploadTrackSystem.id,
                  country: uploadTrackSystem.country,
                  standardsUsed: uploadTrackSystem.standardsUsed,
                  region: uploadTrackSystem.region,
                  company: uploadTrackSystem.company,
                  systemId: uploadTrackSystem.systemId,
                  postalCode: uploadTrackSystem.postalCode,
                  address: uploadTrackSystem.address,
                  city: uploadTrackSystem.city,
                  state: uploadTrackSystem.state,
                  createdAt: uploadTrackSystem.createdAt,
                  updatedAt: uploadTrackSystem.updatedAt,
                  inspectionReport: uploadTrackSystem.inspectionReport,
                  inspectionReports: uploadTrackSystem.inspectionReports,
                  trackIds: trackIndexes,
                };
                this.trackSystemService
                  .doUploadS3TrackSystemCompact(uploadTrackSystemCompact, uploadInspectionJob.uploadUrl)
                  .subscribe((resp) => {
                    if (resp === undefined) {
                      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: "S3 response was undefined",
                        message: `response status is ${resp.status}`,
                        buttons: ["OK"],
                      });
                      alert.present();
                    }
                    if (resp !== undefined) {
                      forkJoin(
                        uploadTrackSystem.tracks.map((track, trackIndex) => {
                          const inspectionJobId = uploadInspectionJob.id;
                          forkJoin(
                            track.assets.map((asset, assetIndex) => {
                              const request: UploadCompactRequestAsset = {
                                inspectionJobId: inspectionJobId,
                                trackIndex: trackIndex,
                                assetIndex: assetIndex,
                              };
                              this.trackSystemService
                                .getAssetUploadUrl(request)
                                .subscribe((response: UploadCompactResponse) => {
                                  const url = response.uploadUrl;
                                  this.trackSystemService.uploadS3Asset(asset, url);
                                });
                            })
                          ).subscribe(() => {
                            const request: UploadCompactRequestTrack = {
                              inspectionJobId: inspectionJobId,
                              trackIndex: trackIndex,
                            };
                            this.trackSystemService
                              .getTrackUploadUrl(request)
                              .subscribe((response: UploadCompactResponse) => {
                                const url = response.uploadUrl;

                                const uploadTrackCompact: TrackCompact = {
                                  id: track.id,
                                  uuid: track.uuid,
                                  trackId: track.trackId,
                                  inspectionId: track.inspectionId,
                                  trackSystemId: track.trackSystemId,
                                  start: track.start,
                                  end: track.end,
                                  trackReport: track.trackReport,
                                  trackReports: track.trackReports,
                                  assetIds: track.assets.map((asset, index) => {
                                    return index;
                                  }),
                                };
                                this.trackSystemService.uploadS3TrackCompact(uploadTrackCompact, url);
                              });
                          });
                        })
                      ).subscribe(() => {
                        this.trackSystemService.setReadyStatus(uploadInspectionJob.id).subscribe(
                          (inspectionJob: InspectionJob) => {
                            this.dismissLoading();
                            // this.uploadButtonDisabled = false;
                            this.awaitInspectionProcessing();
                          },
                          (err) => {
                            this.increaseFailedUploadCount();
                            this.uploadButtonDisabled = false;
                            this.dismissLoading();
                            switch (err.status) {
                              case 401:
                                Utils.sessionExpiredAlert(this.authService, this.alertCtrl, this.navCtrl);
                                break;

                              default:
                                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                                  title: "Error",
                                  subTitle: `There was an error setting the ready status: (${err.status})`,
                                  buttons: ["OK"],
                                });
                                alert.present();
                                break;
                            }
                          }
                        );
                      });
                    } else {
                      this.increaseFailedUploadCount();
                      this.uploadButtonDisabled = false;
                      this.dismissLoading();
                      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: "Error",
                        subTitle: "There was an error uploading to the S3",
                        buttons: ["OK"],
                      });
                      alert.present();
                    }
                  });
              });
          });```
````

Comment: You never return any value from `track.assets.map()`. You probably want `return this.trackSystemService...`

Comment: There's way too much code here shared without any work on creating a minimal repro, so I'm not going to dig into the actual issue. That said, a really quick skim on your code, I'd advise you to look at a few rxjs tutorials and avoid nested subscribes. You're also doing a lot of side effects like affecting global variable within the streams. This goes against the main idea of rxjs and you'll end up with painful debugging sessions

Comment: Yeah I inherited 90% of this code, unfortunately cleaning it up is not a big priority right now. I updated with this return value after each map like suggested and still getting the same thing. 

return this.trackSystemService.uploadS3Asset(asset, url);

return this.trackSystemService.uploadS3TrackCompact(uploadTrackCompact, url);

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion about the tutorials, I don't understand what you're saying about a repo though. Are you saying create a public repo and link here? I did not know that was allowed.

Comment: Will creating a promise.all() if I am calling observables inside of it? I have read RxJs uses promise.all() under the hood anyway, not sure if that correct or not.

Comment: You don't return from within your `map`, which is the same as explicitly returning `undefined`

Comment: ahhh thats it, thank you. So maybe just setting a variable for the end observable and returning that will work?

Comment: I found a way to make it work with Promises, and then just returning Observable.fromPromise(). But this is good to know for the future. I would post the code but it does not really answer the original question I had.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more readable with

```
uploadTrackSystemCompact = {
  ...uploadTrackSystem
  trackIds: trackIndexes,
 };

const uploadTrackCompact: TrackCompact = {
      ...track
      assetIds: track.assets.map((asset, index) => {
        return index;
      }),
    };
```

And It looks like you're dealing with nested subscriptions, which can lead to tightly coupled code and memory leaks. A better approach is to use the switchMap operator to manage these subscriptions more efficiently, ensuring only the most recent subscription is active. Also, consider using the tap operator for side effects without altering the stream. This will make your code cleaner and more maintainable.